# How to deal with changes in the XML Schema (XSD)

Tags: xml, dynamic, xsd, jaxb, moxy

I'm using MOXy to create Dynamic Entities based on an XSD like so:

```
FileInputStream xsdIn = new FileInputStream("customer.xsd");
    DynamicJAXBContext jaxbContext = DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(xsdIn, new MyEntityResolver(), null, null);
    
    //Unmarshaller unmarshaller = (Unmarshaller) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBUnmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    
    
    FileInputStream xmlInputStream = new FileInputStream("dynamicjaxb/customer.xml");
    
    //Unmarshall
    DynamicEntity customer = (DynamicEntity) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlInputStream);
    System.out.println(customer.<String> get("name"));
```

And this is my XSD that I **cannot** change:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:add="http://www.example1.org/address" 
xmlns="http://www.example1.org/customer"
targetNamespace="http://www.example1.org/customer"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xsd:element name="customer">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xsd:element name="address" type="add:address"
                minOccurs="0" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element> </xsd:schema>
```

My question is **what happens if the XSD file changes and, for example, the element `name`changes to something like `firstName`?***

What I'm basically saying is, how do I deal, dynamically, with changes in an XSD file that I do not control?

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically deal with changes in a XSD that someone else controls, as they could do multiple changes and no automated system method will be smart enough to cope.

Usually what happens if a schema is changed with a breaking change (e.g. renaming or deleting an existing item, changing from optional to mandatory etc.), then the party that controls the change should publish it as a new major version, allowing people still to use the old version for a period of time while they transition to the new one.

If it is a non-breaking change (e.g. adding an optional item or changing something from mandatory to optional), then they might elect to publish it as a minor version change and it comes into effect immediately, as it should not cause any issues for existing systems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what would you say is the fastest way to deal with these changes? Like, should I have a config or binding file or I just change the code itself

Comment: So far as I'm aware there aren't config or binding solutions that could cope with schema changes.  So the answer usually would be to update the code if it needs to use a newer version of an xsd.